# Python 3, dictionary, nan replace by 0

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, replace

I have an issue with dictionary:

`dictionary_id_value = {3: nan, 4: 0.0, 5: -10.0, 7: 0.0, 10: -1.0, 12: 0.0, 14: 0.0, 15: 8}`

I want to get key with the maximum and minumum value, so the output should be:

`maximum is 15 and minimum is 5`

I tried to use below cod to do this:

`print(max(dictionary_id_value.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0])
 print(min(dictionary_id_value.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0])`

but due to nan I cannot do this so it should be replaced by 0. Could someone help me with this issue ?

Thanks for all respond

Comment: Create a new dictionary to run against that doesn't contain items which have a value of `nan` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import operator
nan=0
dictionary_id_value = {3: nan, 4: 0.0, 5: -10.0, 7: 0.0, 10: -1.0, 12: 0.0, 14: 0.0, 15: 8}
print('maximum is ' +str(max(dictionary_id_value.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]),end='')
print(' minimum is '+str(min(dictionary_id_value.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]))
```

Output

```
maximum is 15 minimum is 5
```

Comment: But in this case minimum should be 5 because value is -10

Comment: You got your answer @galanonim